# Is there is any way to avoid overlapping of header text in material UI - react?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

[Material UI Header Section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tUQXD.png)

Header section text are overlapping. I need it to show in nextline when overflow. I have tried changing width, alignment, text-align, overflow property, But it seems it not working.

Comment: Did you try to override the material UI CSS for the table head? https://material-ui.com/api/table-head/#css

Comment: Can you provide a working example?